# Android - adding different views(widgets) to the screen without using a layout?

Tags: android

I am preparing to do an android demonstration of sorts and one of the first apps that i would like to write would be a screen filled with different widgets(which of course are views) but would like to put them on the screen without any layout built to hold them. is this possible or do you have to use a layout to put more than one view(widget) on the screen at once?

So right now i can do something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView view1 = new TextView(this);
    view1.setText("I am view one");

    setContentView(view1);




  }
}
```

In this case i really havent specified a layout but there doesnt seem to be a way to position multiple widgets on the screen without setting a layout. The purpose of this would be to show why you would want to use layouts. perhaps there is a way to display widgets on the screen without having to call the setContentView method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add multiple widgets/views to something called a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). If you take a look at the documentation you'll see - not surprisingly - that basically all layouts extend this class. Similarly, if you look up the documentation on e.g. a `TextView`, you'll find that it doesn't extend ViewGroup (it does inherit from `View`, just like ViewGroup, which means it's on a different branch in the hierarchy tree).

In other words: you will need some sort of a layout in order to display more than a single widget/view at a time. You will also always need an explicit call to `setContentView()`, unless you use something like a `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` that by default creates a layout with a ListView as root.

That being said, your example is actually just a programmatical way of setting the following layout on the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="I am view one" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

    TextView view1 = new TextView(this);
    view1.setText("I am view one");
    frameLayout.addView(view1);
    // add more widgets into ViewGroup as you want

    // then set the viewgroup as content view
    setContentView(frameLayout);




  }
```